# Migration to Jakarta EE 10 - 3rd party namespaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, jakarta-migration

I am currently trying to migrate our product from Jakarta EE 8 to Jakarta EE 10. According to the namespace changes of Jakarta APIs I've decided to use intellij Migration tool. After that when I tried to build the application I found out following problem.

We are using 3rd party dependency which has class let's say `Person`. All constructors of particular class throw `javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException`

We had a class `Student` which extends class `Person` so after migration, our class is importing exception class from the new namespace -> `jakarta.activation.MimeTypeParseException;`

```java
import jakarta.activation.MimeTypeParseException;

public class Student extends Person {

  public Student(String name) throws MimeTypeParseException {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

Having the constructor like this, calling `super` is throwing error:
`Unhandled exception javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException`

I've tried to use the newest version of 3rd party package but it still uses the old Javax namespace.

Is there somebody with a similar experience? Or do you know how to solve that, without downloading 3rd party and migrating also its code?

Comment: (1) what is `uses the old Jakarta namespace` ? (2) jakarta.activation.MimeTypeParseException come from `jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar`, it come from jakarta.mail. (3) Old `javax.activation.MimeTypeParseException` come from `activation-1.1.jar` it come from `javax.mail` (4) dirty way , maybe include dependency (<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>) (4) new one is add (
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
)

Comment: of course, I have updated versions of used dependencies, e.g. `jakarta.mail`. Regarding your second suggestion, I thought about that too, but as I need to migrate also to a new server version, this server version doesn't support Jakarta version older than 9 (with package names javax...). So adding particular dependency wouldn't help

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody will face this problem, I've found a [tool](https://github.com/eclipse/transformer) that can help with that problem if you have a 3rd party `.jar` file.

The Transformer tool offers renaming packages within the .jar archive. Renaming is defined in configuration files(e.g. `jakarta-renames.properties`) so you can customize them. For me, the default settings were enough.

After cloning and building Transformer you can run it from your terminal:

```bash
java -jar ~/org.eclipse.transformer.cli-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 3rdparty.jar updatedJar.jar -tr jakarta-renames.properties
```