# Add in Spring boot application a servlet that is not extending jakarta.servlet

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, hessian

I have a legacy application that has this servlet configuration in the **web.xml** file:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HessianServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>home-class</param-name>
      <param-value>com.api.HessianServiceImpl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>home-api</param-name>
      <param-value>com.api.ServicePort</param-value>
    </init-param>       
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HessianServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myhessian/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now I am migrating some parts of the code of the legacy project to another new application that uses spring boot application and also uses other dependencies with more recent versions.

Part of the code that I want to migrate to this new spring boot application would be this HessianServlet configuration added in the **web.xml** file.

The problem I'm running into is that in order to add servlets in spring boot configuration it looks like it needs to be done through the `ServletRegistrationBean`, and this `ServletRegistrationBean` only accepts servlets that extend from `jakarta.servlet`, and the problem is that `com.caucho.hessian.serverHessianServlet` extends from `javax.servlet`.

The spring boot version I'm using is `3.1.0`, and the hessian version is `4.0.66`

I tried by creating a custom `HessianServletWrapper` that was extending `com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianServlet` and implementing `jakarta.servlet.Servlet`

```java
private static class HessianServletWrapper extends HessianServlet implements Servlet {
        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

        }

        @Override
        public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
            return null;
        }
        ...
```

So maybe with this wrapper created I could set it as servlet in the `ServletRegistrationBean`, but the problem is that `com.caucho.hessian.server.HessianServlet` and `jakarta.servlet.Servlet` override the same `getServletConfig()` method and this gives a compilation error.

Anyone would know how could be added in a Spring boot application a servlet that is not extending the `jakarta.servlet`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75156388/migration-to-jakarta-ee-10-3rd-party-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a bad news for you as Spring Boot 3 requires to use [at least Jakarta EE 9](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#minimum-requirements-changes) for the Servlet API (i.e use `jakarta.servlet` instead of `javax.servlet`). And mixing the `jakarta.servlet` and `javax.servlet` is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71181169/339637). I can think some of your best bets are :

1. Use spring boot 2.7
2. Try to make `HessianServlet` to be compatible with `jakarta.servlet` by copying all of its source codes to your project and update everything from `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`. If it works , then you can use spring boot 3+.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will check which one of these options suits me best according to the requirements of the project. Thanks a lot

Comment: Option #1 is not recommended because Spring Boot 2.x will "die" on 2023-11-18, see https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support