# Migrating to jakarta EE from javax EE will not work as dependencies are using javax EE

Tags: jakarta-migration

My project uses some old 3rd party library which the last updated version is at 2009. Now I am trying to migrate the project to use Jakarta EE. I replaced all package namespace "javax" with "jakarta". But some classes extend the 3rd party library classes or call their functions, it causes compile errors: for example: "jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig cannot be converted to javax.servlet.ServletConfig" as the 3rd party library requires the javax.servlet.ServletConfig type variable.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migration to Jakarta EE 10 - 3rd party namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75156388/migration-to-jakarta-ee-10-3rd-party-namespaces)